# extracting two ranges of lines of a file a and putting them as a data block with shell commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I have two blocks of data in a file, say `foo.txt` like the following:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3    
d 4    
e 5
f 6
g 7
h 8
i 9
```

I'd like to extract rows `2:4` and `6:8` and put them as the following:

```
b 2 f 6
c 3 g 7
d 4 h 8
```

I could try using auxiliary files:

```
sed -n '2,4p' foo.txt > tmp1; sed -n '6,8p' foo.txt > tmp2; paste tmp1 tmp2 > output; rm tmp1 tmp2
```

But is there a better way to do it without auxiliary files? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

```
$ paste <(sed -n '2,4p' foo.txt) <(sed -n '6,8p' foo.txt) > output
$ cat output 
b 2 f 6
c 3 g 7
d 4 h 8
$
```

Comment: Thank you, this's what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

In AWK:

```
$ awk 'NR==2,NR==4{a[++i]=$0} NR==6,NR==8{b[++j]=$0} END {for(i=1;i<=j;i++) print a[i],b[i]}' file
b 2 f 6
c 3 g 7
d 4 h 8
```

When between the given record numbers (`NR`), fill up arrays `a` and `b`. In the `END`, print them side by side.